# How to run strapi in the background?

Tags: nginx, server, strapi

I am able to deploy my strapi project to a remote server. How it works? - I connect via the console to the remote nginx server, go to the root of the project and write `npm run develop`, but unfortunately, if I close the terminal (through which I connected to the remote server), the project will close, and I need it to work 24/7.

Question: How to do it?

PS: I could attach nginx configurations here, but I don't know if they are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way of doing this is thru `pm2`:

in root of your project add file `strapi.js` with following config:
`/strapi.js`

```
const strapi = require('@strapi/strapi');
strapi().start();
```

connect to the server via ssh, let's assume that your `strapi` project is located in `/var/www/strapi`

so

```
yarn global add pm2 
OR
npm install pm2@latest -g
```

```
cd /var/www/strapi
pm2 start strapi.js
```

After the process is created
you can do:

```
pm2 stop strapi    // stops server
pm2 start strapi   // starts server
pm2 monit strapi   // monitor server
pm2 list           // lists pm2 processes
```

you can reference [docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/optional-software/process-manager.html)